# jq - How to search for object and show value and full path?

Tags: json, path, jq

I have some JSON (truncated) that is output from Elasticsearch's built-in health status.

```
{
  "gl-system-events_1" : {
    "settings" : {
      "index" : {
        "refresh_interval" : "1s",
        "number_of_shards" : "4",
        "blocks" : {
          "read_only_allow_delete" : "true"
        },
    ...
    ...
```

I'm trying to find every instance of "read_only_allow_delete". These instances may be nested at different levels in the JSON or under different objects. I'd like to show the full path and value (like this):

```
gl-system-events_1.settings.index.block.read_only_allow_delete: true
```

Is there a `grep` equivalent for JSON? I have this command.

```
jq '.. | objects | select(.read_only_allow_delete)'
```

Which produces this output (but I'd like to also see the full path).

```
{
  "read_only_allow_delete": "false",
  "read_only": "false"
}
{
  "read_only_allow_delete": "true"
}
{
  "read_only_allow_delete": "true"
}
{
  "read_only_allow_delete": "true"
}
{
  "read_only_allow_delete": "true"
}
{
  "read_only_allow_delete": "false",
  "read_only": "false"
}
{
  "read_only_allow_delete": "false",
  "read_only": "false"
}
{
  "read_only_allow_delete": "true"
}
{
  "read_only_allow_delete": "false",
  "read_only": "false"
}
```

I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one solution, which produces a stream of [$path, $value] arrays, where $path is the full path shown as an array, and $value is the corresponding value:

```
paths as $path
| getpath($path) as $v
| select($path[-1] == "read_only_allow_delete" )
| [$path, $v]
```

For the sample input, the first pair would be:

```
[["gl-system-events_1","settings","index","blocks","read_only_allow_delete"],"true"]
```

If you really want the ambiguous output, simply tack on:

```
| "\($path|join(".")): \($v)"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you stream the data in, you can get a sequence path/value pairs. You could then filter by the paths.

```
$ jq <input.json --stream 'select(length == 2 and .[0][-1] == "read_only_allow_delete")'
```